# LoadLibrary function return null in Vista and XP

Tags: c#, .net

my app working fine on Win 7 x86 and x64 test environment, but on Vista and XP it does not.

here is the sample code:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
}
....

string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Native");
path = Path.Combine(path, string.Format("x{0}", IntPtr.Size*8));

NativeMethods.SetDllDirectory(path);
IntPtr ptr2 = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("SQLite.Interop.dll");
```

In Vista or XP IntPtr == null no matter x86 or x64.

Solution build target under .net Framework 2, x86.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding .dll to the library name in the DllImport directive?

Comment: Have you checked that `path` is correct? You are apparently adding `x32` or `x64` to the path - but that might not be correct in XP or Vista. Where is the the `SQLite.Interop.dll` installed to?

Comment: Yes i check it, path is correct.

Comment: What does `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` say?

Comment: @guga can you please provide me an example how to do that.

Comment: @Denis, `14001` is `ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX` (incorrect side-by-side configuration). I'd suggest you use `sxstrace` to diagnose the problem. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/14/576314.aspx) for more information.

Comment: What guga means is that `DllImport("kernel32",...` is missing `.dll`. Make it `DllImport("kernel32.dll",...`

Comment: 14001 is ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX: "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail." according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681384(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I still cant solve this issue just with Microsoft.VC90.CRT folder, but installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86) is working fine. Thank you for help EricSchaefer!

Comment: The obvious problem is that the path is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 IntPtr ptr2 = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("SQLite.Interop.dll");
```

That's not a native library, that's a .NET interop library for SQLite.  It contains managed class declarations.  You'll need to use Assembly.LoadFrom() to load it.  Although you almost always prefer just adding the it as a reference to your project, *much* easier to write code that way.  You probably still need SetDllDirectory() because SQLite is at its core unmanaged code written in C so the wrapper probably needs help to find sqlite.dll.

Not sure why you are doing this, probably has something to do with 64-bit operating systems.  Keep in mind that that's a deployment problem, not a programming problem.